# how to check Waiting period,Content download in Jemter?

Tags: automation, jmeter, performance-testing

I wanted to check how long service take to generate the data.
i am using Jmeter but it shows only Sample time (ms) and not the waiting time or content download time.
I hvae check in Chrome-developer tool but i need some automation and assertion for response (i am looking for tool to do it. )
It will be grate help if anyone knows how to check in Jmeter or with anyother tool.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverTutorial/) which provides JMeter integration with [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/), you will be able to use [Navigation Timing API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Navigation_timing_API) to get the metrics you're looking for like:

```
WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
WDS.browser.get('http://jmeter.apache.org')
var timings = WDS.browser.executeScript('var performance = window.performance || window.webkitPerformance || window.mozPerformance || window.msPerformance || {}; var timings = performance.timing || {}; return timings;');
var vars = org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContextService.getContext().getVariables()
vars.put('connectStart', timings.connectStart)
vars.put('loadEventStart', timings.loadEventStart)
//etc    
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
```

You will be able to access extracted variables like:

- `${connectStart}`
- `${loadEventStart}`
- etc.

and use them in calculations, assertions or whatever.

See [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered) article for more WebDriver Sampler related tips and tricks